# Php file upload, check file type

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have this code, what i use for uploading multiple files.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    if(isset($_FILES['gallery']))
    {
        if($_FILES["gallery"]["size"] > 0 )
        {
            foreach($_FILES['gallery']["name"] AS $key=>$file)
            {
                if($_FILES['gallery']['size'][$key]  != 0 )
                {
                    $target_path = "../documents/" . date( "Y-m-d" ) . '-' . rand(10, 999999999) . '-' . $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key];
                    $fajl_nev = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs,  $_POST["images_alt"][ $key ] );                  
                    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path ))
                    {
                        $file_name = basename($target_path);
                        $sql = 
                        "
                            INSERT INTO letoltheto_fajl
                            (
                                fajl_nev,
                                fajl_file,
                                fajl_datetime
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                '$fajl_nev',
                                '$file_name',
                                NOW()
                            )
                        ";
                        mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
                        header("Location: ".$host."/".$admin_folder."/feltoltott-fajlok.php?new=1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error[] = "A fájl feltöltése nem sikerült, próbálja újra.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i check, the files type? I give the allowed file types in an array below:

```
    $allowed_files = array
(
    "image/jpg", 
    "image/jpeg", 
    "image/bmp", 
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
    "application/pdf"
);
```

And i also want to allow more files, like excel, word...How can i give these types? Is there any content, where i can read about this?

Comment: If you are doing this for learning purposes, no problem.. but you can checkout https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof and safe yourself the hustle. It's my repo, I'm not advertising, but I think it'll do what you want. If you want to upload other types of files check https://github.com/brandonsavage/Upload

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the file extension or mime. Try something like this:

```
$allowedFiles =  array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg, 'bmp', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx'); // etc...
$filename = $_FILES['gallery']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext, $allowedFiles) ) {
    echo 'Error...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The txt isnt in the allowed list, and it lets me upload txt files also.

```
$allowed_files = array
```

(
    // Images
    'png'  => 'image/png',
    'jpe'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'gif'  => 'image/gif',
    'bmp'  => 'image/bmp',

```
// PDF files
'pdf'  => 'application/pdf',

// Tömörített fájlok
'zip'  => 'application/zip',
'rar'  => 'application/x-rar-compressed',

// MS office
'doc'  => 'application/msword',
'rtf'  => 'application/rtf',
'xls'  => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'ppt'  => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

// Open Office
'odt'  => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
'ods'  => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'
```

);

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    if(isset($_FILES['gallery']))
    {
        if($_FILES["gallery"]["size"] > 0 )
        {
            foreach($_FILES['gallery']["name"] AS $key=>$file)
            {
                if($_FILES['gallery']['size'][$key]  != 0 )
                {

                    $filename = $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key];
                    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(!in_array($ext, $allowed_files[0]) ) 
                    {
                        $error[] = "Nem engedélyezett fájl típus.";
                    }

                    $target_path = "../documents/" . date( "Y-m-d" ) . '-' . rand(10, 999999999) . '-' . $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key];
                    $fajl_nev = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs,  $_POST["images_alt"][ $key ] );                  
                    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path ))
                    {
                        $file_name = basename($target_path);
                        $sql = 
                        "
                            INSERT INTO letoltheto_fajl
                            (
                                fajl_nev,
                                fajl_file,
                                fajl_datetime
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                '$fajl_nev',
                                '$file_name',
                                NOW()
                            )
                        ";
                        mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
                        header("Location: ".$host."/".$admin_folder."/feltoltott-fajlok.php?new=1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error[] = "A fájl feltöltése nem sikerült, próbálja újra.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file type from the file content not the client mimetype.

```
if(in_array(mime_type($file_path),$allowed_mime_types)){
    // save the file
}

$allowed_mime_types = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'video/mp4'
);


/*
For PHP>=5.3.0, you can use php's `finfo_file`([finfo_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)) function to get the file infomation about the file.

For PHP<5.3.0, you can use your's system's `file` command to get the file information.
*/
function mime_type($file_path)
{
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {            
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, null);
        $mime_type = $finfo->file($file_path);
    }
    if (!$mime_type && function_exists('passthru') && function_exists('escapeshellarg')) {
        ob_start();
        passthru(sprintf('file -b --mime %s 2>/dev/null', escapeshellarg($file_path)), $return);
        if ($return > 0) {
            ob_end_clean();
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $type = trim(ob_get_clean());
        if (!preg_match('#^([a-z0-9\-]+/[a-z0-9\-\.]+)#i', $type, $match)) {
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $mime_type = $match[1];
    }
    return $mime_type;
}
```